# How to use Listview in Flipview in WinJS

Tags: windows, listview, winjs, flipview

I have different genres and each genre contains different music albums. I want that to be displayed like

> Genre Name 1 
>  ListView[with horizontal scroll and with left and right
>   arrows]
>   Genre Name 2 
>  ListView[with horizontal scroll and with left and right
>   arrows]
>   Genre Name 3 
>  ListView[with horizontal scroll and with left and right
>   arrows]

Similar to Windows STore App. How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Hub control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn255137.aspx) and set the [orientation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn255141.aspx) to vertical. You can set the [isHeaderStatic property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn255126.aspx) of your [HubSections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn255127.aspx) to true if you do not want to display the "See More" link on the top right of each section.

Let me know if that answers your question!

Comment: how do we get arrows? If I add ListLayout(horizontal) inside hub section, whole list moves along with hub section header